# How to escape a javascript 's "\"

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework

Inside a render function in my template I'm passing this parameter:

```
placeholderTitle: (gettext "Companie\'s name")
```

I need to escape the `'` because that string is going to be used inside inline javascript:

```
onfocus="if (this.textContent.trim() == 'Companie's name') {//do someting}"
```

But like that is not working.

Comment: `"Companie\\'s name"`?

Comment: @mudasobwa I tried that but it would make one '\' visible in the final string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Poison.encode!` to encode variables that are to be printed in JS code. The following should work if you pass this as an attribute to HTML helpers like `content_tag`:

```
onfocus: "if (this.textContent.trim() == #{Poison.encode!(gettext("Companie's name"))} {//do someting}"
```

Comment: I realised that there's a better way of making this validation using a data-attribute without the extra burden on the Elixir side, so although this could work I think it's not the best approach as a general approach, not as an Elixir solution.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, go with the data attribute solution. That would be much better and simpler and won't require any JSON encoding if the value is a simple string: `data: [text: gettext("...")]`.